# Schema(Star ratings) is not applied to my site

Tags: schema, json-ld

I applied schema(Star Ratings) in my site,It took more than 5 days, I checked in google structured data testing tool also, there is no errors and no warnings still it is not applied. Can anyone help to fix this issue?

I tried Schema for my Local Business

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "Abs Travels",
  "image": "https://www.abstravels.biz/images/5star.png",
  "description": "ABS Travels offers all types of travel related services under one roof that are known for our excellent and efficient travel services provider in Tirunelveli.",
  "address": {
"@type": "PostalAddress",
"addressLocality": "Tirunelveli",
"addressRegion": "TN",
"streetAddress": "24, Ramarsamy Kovil Street",
"postalCode": " 627002",
"addressCountry": "INDIA"
},
"priceRange" : "₹5000 - ₹10000",
"telephone": "+919843326422",
   "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "5",
    "bestRating": "5",
    "ratingCount": "97"

  }
}
</script>
```

I expect Schema to be applied to my site(Star Ratings) there is no error messages.Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. If Google tooling says your schema is correct but it's not showing in their results, not sure how anyone other than Google can help you.

Answer (score 1):

No way to answer (Correct JSON-LD is not enough**). Some ideas:

- "**Not homepage"**: Google doesn't display Stars for companies' homepage.
- **"over stars not related to page subject/content**": Do not add Schema stars for **all** pages in your site (Risk for Google penalties).
- **Check your code** https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

**Anyway Read this:**

> Important: Google does not guarantee that your structured data will show up in search results, even if your page is marked up correctly according to the Structured Data Testing Tool... [Google official docs - data guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)

**Follow the structured data guidelines**

In your case you not follow this rule "**Don't mark up content that is not visible to readers of the page"** - More rules:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies

**Review-snippet guidelines**

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet#guidelines

**`google serach console` ==> URL Inspection Tool ==> inspection requests**

Speed up the way google show results:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en

### Related:

https://whitespark.ca/blog/how-to-use-aggregate-review-schema-to-get-stars-in-the-serps/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If schema is to apply, May i know approximately how many days will it take to reflect?

Comment: No way. Req indexing under google search console for faster updates.